# How to Manipulate a Dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, dataset, csv

I have a raw dataset of Images I got from Kaggle, It has been classified already, but I want to randomly split the information in a 80:20 ratio between train and test, problem is since all information is classified, I'd love to keep that folder classification in my new train set while all is mixed in the test folder. I cant do it myself since I want it to be randomly split, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

From this dataset, you should prepare new variables namely, `X` and `y`; where `X = feature matrix` and `y = class variable`. Now, use the following code to split the data into train and test dataset of desired proportion -

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

The `test_size` helps you prepare a train-test split of 80:20; and 
the `random_state` is the seed value for randomisation. 
Each different seed shall yield a different randomised split.